# Change values based on conditions with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a `pandas` equivalent of `numpy.where`, which allows you to change values in a way that there're two options to choose from depending on the condition (True/False)?. However, `pandas.where` is similiar, but not what I want.

Comment: You didn't specify why `dp.Series.where` isn't what you want.  It might be because you don't know how to use it.  Did you know that you can pass another argument that replaces the value when the first argument is `False`.  This in effect acts just like `numpy.where` when used correctly.  However, you asked a question and basically took away the only answer that answers your question.  Why don'y you show us what you want to do?

Comment: @piRSquared thank you for pointing it out. Appreciate it a lot. It's weird I don't see it in its documentation though. I should've waited a bit longer and see if there would be better suggestions. But the answer did do the trick. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.where()` directly;

```
df['column'] = np.where(df['column'] > 50, 100, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought `numpy.where` returning an array instead of a series or a dataframe would cause problems.

Comment: Pandas overrides the equals assignment operator to ensure that things like this is possible. If this helped please accept it as the correct answer so others can benefit too. Good luck.